# Spacing of consecutive equation versus a single gather

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath

I know the spacing produced by the following two approaches is slightly different. So my question is which one should I choose? Is it about personal preference?

### With 3 consecutive `equation` environments

[image: spacing example]

### With a single `gather` environment

[image: gather example]

### Code

```
\documentclass[preview,multi,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{preview}
The following equations are too simple,
\begin{equation}
v_t=v_0+at
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
s=v_0t+\tfrac{1}{2}at^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_t^2=v_0^2+2as
\end{equation}
where $a$ is the acceleration.
\end{preview}


\begin{preview}
The following equations are too simple,
\begin{gather}
v_t=v_0+at\\
s=v_0t+\tfrac{1}{2}at^2\\
v_t^2=v_0^2+2as
\end{gather}
where $a$ is the acceleration.
\end{preview}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply looking at the result shows that the separate `equation` environments are wrong. Can you see the different interline spacing?

Comment: @egreg : interline spacing between the equations?

Comment: personally I would prefer `alignat` which gives same spacing as `gather`.

Comment: Look between equation (1) and (2), and between (2) and (3). No way this can be "personal preference": it's wrong spacing.

Comment: @egreg: It should be regarded as unbalanced spacing (rather than wrong spacing) I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't do it with 3 consecutive `equation`s. As you said yourself, the spacing is unbalanced. Here's why: The line before the first `equation` is "long", so TeX uses `\abovedisplayskip` above it, and `\belowdisplayskip` below. The other two equation don't have text before them, or you could say the text before the equations is "short". Thus, TeX uses `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip`. As a result, you have

- `\belowdisplayskip` + `\abovedisplayshortskip` between the 1st and the 2nd equation, and
- `\belowdisplayshortskip` + `\abovedisplayshortskip` between the 2nd and the 3rd equation.

I'd use `align` (and not `gather`) to obtain horizontal alignment *and* balanced vertical spacing:

```
\begin{align}
  v_t &= v_0 + at \\
    s &= v_0t + \tfrac{1}{2} at^2 \\
v_t^2 &= v_0^2 + 2as
\end{align}
```

Comment: What convention do we usually adopt to decide whether or not we need to use gather instead of align for consecutive equations? I am confused to make such a decision. I know it is about horizontal alignment for sure.

Comment: If you have "natural" points for horizontal alignment, then use `align`. An `0` or `\le` sign is such a "natural" point.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
s=v_0t+\tfrac{1}{2}at^2
```

produces a fraction which here does not give you a higher line. If you used a `\frac{}{}` instead, it might happen that one line will be higher than the others (if they are wo fractions), which is also unnatural. Then it helps to put `\phantom{\frac{1}{2}}` on the end of the other lines (after the dot or comma sign). At least then, even with consecutive equations, which I don't recommend, the spacing would be balanced.